# Can't call method inside of a inherited class from Main

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, methods

I have created a basic template program helping me understand Interfaces, classes and the such.

What I am trying to achieve is simply calling a method that resides in an inherited class hierarchy.

I am getting this error:

> 'Book' does not contain a definition for 'BulkOrder' and no extension method for 'BulkOrder' accepting a first argument of type 'Book' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**This is the main program**

```
Main
{
 BulkBook book2 = new BulkBook(FILLER);
 BulkOrder(book2);
}


public static void BulkOrder(Book book2)
{ 
Console.WriteLine(Filler text);
book2.BulkOrder(); <------- belongs in inherited class
}
```

**This is the inherited class structure**

```
 abstract class Publication
 various code
 class Book : Publication
 various code 
 class BulkBook : Book
 various code
 public void BulkOrder() <------ method
    {
        Copies = Copies + BATCH_SIZE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BulkOrder` exists in `BulkBook` and not `Book` you need to cast `book2` to `BulkBook`:

```
((BulkBook)book2).BulkOrder();
```

However you may wish to verify that `book2` is in fact a `BulkBook`:

```
if (book2 is BulkBook)
{
  ((BulkBook)book2).BulkOrder();
}
```

An alternative solution would be to have the method accept the type `BulkBook` rather than `Book`:

```
public static void BulkOrder(BulkBook book2)
{ 
Console.WriteLine(Filler text);
book2.BulkOrder(); //This should now work
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that fixed it. casting is something our lecturers do not tell us about, it's rather frustrating, I pay £7800 a year and casting doesn't come into the course material

Comment: I thought casting was only used when referring to variable data types?

Comment: The reason this works in your main method is that your main method "knows" that your object is the inherited type `BulkBook`.  However, when you passed it to the method (which accepted the base type `Book`) it doesn't know anything more about it until you specify.

Comment: Casting has a bunch of uses, in this case you want tell the compiler that it is a specific version of `Book` that you're dealing with.  I'm going to update my answer with an alternative way to deal with your situation

Comment: @DannyWatson Do note that downcasting like this *usually* means you are doing something wrong, and **always** check if the cast will succeed (or be ready for `InvalidCastException`)

Answer (score 2):

```
class BulkBook : Book
    ...
    public void BulkOrder()
    {
        Copies = Copies + BATCH_SIZE;
    }
```

The `BulkOrder` method only exists in the `BulkBook` class, not the `Book` class.

Comment: More importantly, upcasting is free. downcasting is **not**.

Comment: This answer was not very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @DannyWatson : Above answer tells you the root cause of the error. The issue is with type.